# head: illegal option -- q

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

Trying to count number of columns in csv files within a directory using: `head -n 1 *.csv | awk -F, '{print NF}'`

It result with many zeros as `head` print the name of the file first. Tried `head -q -n 1 *.csv` which usually works on standard Linux servers, but here (local Mac) I get:

```
head: illegal option -- q
usage: head [-n lines | -c bytes] [file ...]
```

Funny enough, in `man head` I don't even see `-q` as a valid argument.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else has already explained in another answer why it didn't work. And here is a portable workaround:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 {print NF}' *.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! It's slower than grep though. Why can be the reason?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel A slow awk implementation. Try `awk -F, 'FNR==1 {print NF; nextfile}' *.csv` and see if it works/helps, I am not sure if macos awk supports `nextfile`.

Comment: That's much faster!

Answer (score 2):

That's because it is not a legal argument.

The POSIX standard detailed which command line flags were necessary for key programs (like head, tail, and much of binutils) and the GNU organization has occasionally added additional flags that extend beyond the standard.

This is an additional "-q" quiet flag that's not part of the POSIX standard, but part of the GNU offering, and you've wandered onto a platform that isn't using GNU's offering of utilities.

I suggest you just script around it, or use a pipeline of grep, etc. to only retain the lines you need.

Comment: Fortunately, there aren't many of these problems out there.  Good luck.

Comment: or install `gawk`

Comment: @markp-fuso While that's an option for people who control their own platforms, when writing portable scripts such options become just as problematic, if not more so, than the problem they solve.  It's a good idea for one to have some exposure to portable bash, even if it isn't needed right away, as one day it likely will be needed when one doesn't have time to develop it.

Comment: Jeez... Thanks @Edwin Buck. And yes, that's the first time I encounter such an incident. Per your response, I used grep to walkaround this. ```head -n 1 *.csv | grep -v "==>" |grep -v -e '^$'|awk -F, '{print NF}' ```

Comment: omg... As a habit, try not to chain programs like this when one could handle the entire logic of the chain. For small tasks it's no big deal, but why spawn a `head` *and two* `grep`s when you're already calling `awk` anyway? `awk` will usually do whatever you wanted from all of those. Also, look carefully at your logic; `head` pays no attention to the content of the one record, just exits after the first line, but you have *two* greps excluding lines before `awk` receives data. That might be exactly what you want, but it might be better to just write your logic in `awk` to be clear.